# Insert a multiline string

Tags: insert

Would it be considered normal (common and good style) to use `insert` with a multiline string ?

```
(insert "This is the first line \n
that gets continued on the second line \n
and on the third line")
```

Comment: If you had just typed this in your `*scratch*` buffer and evaluated it, you would immediately see the problem.

Comment: The `\n`, but apart from that, it prints good.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "normal" ? Do you mean, is this considered "good style" when it comes to writing emacs-lisp code?

Comment: Asking if it would be good style,

Answer (score 2):

The emacs lisp manual has a section on conventions :  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Tips.html

That section has a subsection for coding conventions.

The community has also rallied around this style guide: https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-lisp-style-guide

As well as this guidebook for package development: https://alphapapa.github.io/emacs-package-dev-handbook/